# Xamarin C# PCL - json content to listview

Tags: c#, json, listview, xamarin.forms

I'm learning Xamarin and was trying to push this Jira Json output to a listview named ListView1. If anyone would like to help a newbie please by all means. Everything works up to outputting data in debug, when i output the content but does not go to the list view. What am I doing wrong?

Note I had to use DataContract for Avatar URLS because it was bringing up invalid when ran in json2sharp. not sure if thats correct.

Here is a sample of the Json OUTPUT https://0bin.net/paste/8vbm-XlwIPcuxCeL#qG-rL5BzxIzCNx/3LpUdO8VMukLuFiAvG7+wHdNbra5 which I made into a Class, (Working with Jira output)

```
public class ItemClass
    {
        public class Links
        {
            public string @base { get; set; }
            public string context { get; set; }
            public string self { get; set; }
        }

        public class CreatedDate
        {
            public string iso8601 { get; set; }
            public string jira { get; set; }
            public string friendly { get; set; }
            public object epochMillis { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class AvatarUrls
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "48x48")]
            public string Icon_48x48 { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "24x24")]
            public string Icon_24x24 { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "16x16")]
            public string Icon_16x16 { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "32x32")]
            public string Icon_32x32 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Links2
        {
            public string jiraRest { get; set; }
            public AvatarUrls avatarUrls { get; set; }
            public string self { get; set; }
        }

        public class Reporter
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string key { get; set; }
            public string emailAddress { get; set; }
            public string displayName { get; set; }
            public bool active { get; set; }
            public string timeZone { get; set; }
            public Links2 _links { get; set; }
        }

        public class RequestFieldValue
        {
            public string fieldId { get; set; }
            public string label { get; set; }
            public object value { get; set; }
        }

        public class StatusDate
        {
            public string iso8601 { get; set; }
            public string jira { get; set; }
            public string friendly { get; set; }
            public object epochMillis { get; set; }
        }

        public class CurrentStatus
        {
            public string status { get; set; }
            public StatusDate statusDate { get; set; }
        }

        public class Links3
        {
            public string web { get; set; }
            public string self { get; set; }
        }

        public class Value
        {
            public List<string> _expands { get; set; }
            public string issueId { get; set; }
            public string issueKey { get; set; }
            public string requestTypeId { get; set; }
            public string serviceDeskId { get; set; }
            public CreatedDate createdDate { get; set; }
            public Reporter reporter { get; set; }
            public List<RequestFieldValue> requestFieldValues { get; set; }
            public CurrentStatus currentStatus { get; set; }
            public Links3 _links { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<string> _expands { get; set; }
            public int size { get; set; }
            public int start { get; set; }
            public int limit { get; set; }
            public bool isLastPage { get; set; }
            public Links _links { get; set; }
            public List<Value> values { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Code when executed to display:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = "";
                string url = "https://***/rest/servicedeskapi/request";
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", baseauth);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemClass.RootObject>>(content);
                ListView1.ItemsSource = Items;
```

Listview on xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1" RowHeight="60">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="8,0,8,0">
                                <Label Text="{Binding reporter}" TextColor="#000" FontSize="14" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: your ItemSource is a List<RootObject>, and your Label is bound to "reporter", but RootObject does not have a "reporter" property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding to a `List<RootObject>`. And in your `Cell` you bind to the `reporter` property. The `RootObject` however, does not have a `reporter` property. So either add the `reporter` to it or, looking at your code, make the `ItemsSource`: `Items.values`, which has the `reporter` property.

So change your code like this:

```
var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemClass.RootObject>>(content);
ListView1.ItemsSource = Items.values;
```

Comment: Ah I was under the impression that as it was deserializeing to an object list in side root, it would then just post all values in the class via Items. 

How do I go about getting the values/objects? like Items.values as it seems to be invalid for Items.values

Comment: Nope it will bind to the type that is in the list that you set the `ItemsSource` to and only the properties in that object are available to you

Comment: Oh It shed light but no alas my problem still not solved. Trying to figure out how to display the output as Items.values is not defined value for itemssource.

Comment: You mean the values property is null or? Also you can't use the `reporter` directly as it is a complex type. Try setting it to something like `reporter.name` or override the `ToString` of the `Reporter` class

Comment: Was just using reporter as a test, but im trying to push all the content received from the json output into the list view. none of the steps ive tried seem to help, I'll prob have to go look at some example PCL's and try out some things.

Comment: Without telling what you have tried and where you fail or what your end goal is, it's kind of hard to be of any assitance

Comment: First, can you confirm that "Items" indeed contains all of the data you expect, after the call to deserialize object?  If so, what DO you get in the lsitview after doing "{Binding Items.values.reporter}"? I would expect you get a listview with "<namespace>.ItemClass.Reporter" in it, because you are doing a ToString on an object (Reporter) which does not override the ToString implementation.

Comment: So I kinda thought I had it but, no still trying to figure it out, I changed it to.. 

Ticket.RootObject Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticket.RootObject>(content);
                    ListView1.ItemsSource = Items._expands.ToArray();

and my XAML to <Label Text="{Binding}" TextColor="White"></Label>

It prints out the _expands fine, but how do I access its children? 

when I changed namespace from Ticket.RootObject to like Ticket.Reporter it wouldn't display out any text. Seems like the only stored info it reports out is from the class with: public List<string>

Comment: So I get this output atm.. 

Ticket.RootObject Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticket.RootObject>(content);
                    var name = Items.values[0].reporter.name;
                    ListView1.ItemsSource = name;

[0:] Binding: 'name' property not found on 'd', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text' 

It spits out one char for the stored string d = start of the email address it was outputting as the name value. how do I combine it to entire word? Or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to set the `ItemsSource` to a collection on some sorts. Right now you are setting it to a collection of chars, namely a string. Set the `ItemsSource` to `Items` and then you can bind to `reporter.name`. Think of it this way; the list gets bind to a collection of a certain object type. Now each cell represents one entry in that collection. This cell can bind to any property that is in that object type. And cells are repeatedly shown for each actual object in the collection. I hope it makes it a bit more clear